# File upload to Gridview and store the information ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

Here's the scenario, when I upload a file, I read the file and dump its content in a gridView. When I upload another file, it should also append the gridView with the new items.

What happens with mine is that whenever I upload a new file, it replaces the old one. Is it possible to store the data from dataGridview on a temporary holder?

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if (Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) == ".xlsx")
        {
            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(FileUpload1.FileContent);
            GridView1.DataSource = package.ToDataTable();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        if (FileUpload1.FileName.Contains("0446") == true)
        {
            Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[6].Cells[0].Text);
            Name2 = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[6].Cells[1].Text);
            InsertToFileSource("0446",Name, Name2);
            double totalAquirerSettlement = Convert.ToDouble(Name2);

            Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[13].Cells[0].Text);
            Name2 = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[13].Cells[1].Text);
            InsertToFileSource("0446", Name, Name2);
            double totalLoadSettlement = Convert.ToDouble(Name2);

            InsertToNAV("21-01-041-00000 P/R - Clearing Account - Missing",Convert.ToString(totalAquirerSettlement+totalLoadSettlement));

            Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[18].Cells[0].Text);
            Name2 = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[18].Cells[1].Text);
            InsertToFileSource("0446", Name, Name2);
            InsertToNAV("21-01-044-00000 P/R - Clearing Account Write off",Name2);

            Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[26].Cells[0].Text);
            Name2 = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[26].Cells[3].Text);
            InsertToFileSource("0446", Name, Name2);
            InsertToNAV("21-01-031-00000 Issuerliab - CMgr", Name2);
        }
        if (FileUpload1.FileName.Contains("0501A") == true)
        {
            //calculateRNP();
            InsertToNAV("21-01-032-00000 Issuerliab – Manual Adjustments", calculateRNP());
        }
        if (FileUpload1.FileName.Contains("Non-Rail") == true)
        {
            String merchant_Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[9].Cells[5].Text);
            String nonRail_Amount = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[40].Cells[6].Text);
            InsertToFileSource("SFF", merchant_Name, nonRail_Amount);
            InsertToNAV(merchant_Name, nonRail_Amount);
        }
        if (FileUpload1.FileName.Contains("Rail") == true)
        {
            //String merchant_Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[9].Cells[5].Text);
            //String nonRail_Amount = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[40].Cells[6].Text);
        }
    }
}

protected void InsertToFileSource(String FileType,String Name, String Name2)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["FileSource"];
    if(Name == "Total Acquirer Settlement"||Name == "Total Load Acquirer Settlement")
        dt.Rows.Add(FileType, Name, Name2, "P/R - Clearing Account Missing ");
    if (Name == "Sub Total:")
        dt.Rows.Add(FileType, Name, Name2, "P/R - Clearing Account WriteOff ");
    if(Name == "Net Total :")
        dt.Rows.Add(FileType, Name, Name2, "Issuerliab - CMgr ");
    if (Name == "RNP")
        dt.Rows.Add(FileType, Name, Name2, "Issuerliab – Manual Adjustments");
    else
        dt.Rows.Add(FileType, Name, Name2, "SFF Non-Rail");

    this.BindGridView3();
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtGridView2 = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("Document Source"),new DataColumn("Line Item Entry"), new DataColumn("Amount"), new DataColumn("NAV Account") });
    ViewState["FileSource"] = dt;
    this.BindGridView3();

    dtGridView2.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Merchant Name"), new DataColumn("Debit"), new DataColumn("Credit") });
    ViewState["StatementOfAccounts"] = dtGridView2;
    this.BindGridView2();
}
```

Comment: Can you please put up some code it will help to understand better.

Comment: Hi Nayan, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your data to DataTable before setting that to the grid, make a check, if there is already some data within your DataTable , append the new data with that, don't create new DataTable every time. So, your grid will have fresh data every time the new file comes.

Comment: How do I save the data to the Datatable before I set it to grid? Basically I have to append data in GridView2 and 3 always.

Comment: You can save it in ViewState or SessionState,

Answer (score 0):

```
    //you must make a class named data, and this class will be bind to GridView1.DataSource
//this is a new line
    private static List<data> datasources = new List<data>();

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) == ".xlsx")
                {
                    ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(FileUpload1.FileContent);
    datasources.add(package.ToDataTable()); // keep ToDataTable return type is same with data
//here have some edit
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }

                if (FileUpload1.FileName.Contains("0446") == true)
                {
                    Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[6].Cells[0].Text);
                    Name2 = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[6].Cells[1].Text);
                    InsertToFileSource("0446",Name, Name2);
                    double totalAquirerSettlement = Convert.ToDouble(Name2);

                    Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[13].Cells[0].Text);
                    Name2 = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[13].Cells[1].Text);
                    InsertToFileSource("0446", Name, Name2);
                    double totalLoadSettlement = Convert.ToDouble(Name2);

                    InsertToNAV("21-01-041-00000 P/R - Clearing Account - Missing",Convert.ToString(totalAquirerSettlement+totalLoadSettlement));

                    Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[18].Cells[0].Text);
                    Name2 = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[18].Cells[1].Text);
                    InsertToFileSource("0446", Name, Name2);
                    InsertToNAV("21-01-044-00000 P/R - Clearing Account Write off",Name2);

                    Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[26].Cells[0].Text);
                    Name2 = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[26].Cells[3].Text);
                    InsertToFileSource("0446", Name, Name2);
                    InsertToNAV("21-01-031-00000 Issuerliab - CMgr", Name2);

                }
                if (FileUpload1.FileName.Contains("0501A") == true)
                {
                    //calculateRNP();
                    InsertToNAV("21-01-032-00000 Issuerliab – Manual Adjustments", calculateRNP());
                }
                if (FileUpload1.FileName.Contains("Non-Rail") == true)
                {
                    String merchant_Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[9].Cells[5].Text);
                    String nonRail_Amount = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[40].Cells[6].Text);
                    InsertToFileSource("SFF", merchant_Name, nonRail_Amount);
                    InsertToNAV(merchant_Name, nonRail_Amount);
                }
                if (FileUpload1.FileName.Contains("Rail") == true)
                {
                    //String merchant_Name = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[9].Cells[5].Text);
                    //String nonRail_Amount = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[40].Cells[6].Text);
                }
            }
        }

       protected void InsertToFileSource(String FileType,String Name, String Name2)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["FileSource"];
            if(Name == "Total Acquirer Settlement"||Name == "Total Load Acquirer Settlement")
                dt.Rows.Add(FileType, Name, Name2, "P/R - Clearing Account Missing ");
            if (Name == "Sub Total:")
                dt.Rows.Add(FileType, Name, Name2, "P/R - Clearing Account WriteOff ");
            if(Name == "Net Total :")
                dt.Rows.Add(FileType, Name, Name2, "Issuerliab - CMgr ");
            if (Name == "RNP")
                dt.Rows.Add(FileType, Name, Name2, "Issuerliab – Manual Adjustments");
            else
                dt.Rows.Add(FileType, Name, Name2, "SFF Non-Rail");

            this.BindGridView3();
        }
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtGridView2 = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("Document Source"),new DataColumn("Line Item Entry"), new DataColumn("Amount"), new DataColumn("NAV Account") });
            ViewState["FileSource"] = dt;
            this.BindGridView3();

            dtGridView2.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Merchant Name"), new DataColumn("Debit"), new DataColumn("Credit") });
            ViewState["StatementOfAccounts"] = dtGridView2;
            this.BindGridView2();

    //there are new lines
            GridView1.DataSource = datasources;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Johan, GridView2 is what I need to save because every file I add a new row. But what happens with mine is that it overwrites or creates a new instance.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is what question you need solve. we must be keeping the data when we reload page! in my code i used to a  static variable what is named `datasources` to keep these data, and i bind the variable to GridView1(in your code maybe you need bind to GridView2). normally when you reload a page, every non-static variable in this page will be redefinition.

Comment: Hi Johan, I was able to do it already. Although I'm not quite sure what I changed with the code though.

Comment: Does  it work now? You can see this link maybe can help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yep it doe wrok. But now I'm confused as to why it does work.

Comment: You may know in ASP.NET `Page` is a class, and all `Controls` who are run on server are variables.So, when you request a page, this page will be initialization and variables in this `Page` are initialization. In your code `GridView1`, `GridView2`  or other  will be initialization in every per request. But static variable just be initialization for once when the class first to used. When you understand these, you can see in my code, i set a variable named `datasources `, this is a static vaiable, it can keep the data in multiple requests!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a database you should first put the value of the excel file to your database and then call the function that binds the table of your database to your gridview. Works for me.